# Should I use MAMP vhost or php artisan?

Tags: laravel-5.1, mamp, laravel-artisan

I've had difficulties getting MAMP to cooperate with laravel installs. Seemingly issues with .htaccess and other configurations. That all being said, my question is, are there any benefits of using MAMP vhost over php artisan for my local server? Will I be missing out on anything or is php artisan actually the preferred/recommended way of developing for laravel?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, as close to the production environment as possible is probably ideal. So for AMP stuff I would always just go LAMP over MAMP or WAMP using a VM or similar. Things just work better.

Comment: So you're saying I would be best served by using something like homestead/vagrant with php artisan?